# Ripple effect BottomNavigationView freezes when using setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, bottomnavigationview

When I use `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` the `BottomNavigationView` freezes on ripple effects like the screenshot below. And the effect state keep staying like this.

I don't understand why?

I'm using `com.android.support:design:27.1.1`

```
binding = DataBindingUtil
        .setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

bottomBar = binding?.bottomBarNavigation as BottomNavigationView
bottomBar?.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    when (it.itemId) {
        TabBarObject.TAB_MESSENGER -> replaceFragment(
            MessengerFragment(),
            TabBarObject.TAB_MESSENGER.tabName
        )
        ...
        ...
    }
}

private fun getTabInfo(menuItemId: Int): TabBarObject {
    return when (menuItemId) {
        R.id.tab_messenger -> TabBarObject.TAB_MESSENGER
        ...
        ...
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("UNKNOWN TAB BAR TYPE")
    }
}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String): Boolean {
    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment, tag)
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    return true
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_bar_navigation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_navigation"
            style="@style/BottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottombar_tabs" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**bottombar_tabs.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tab_messenger"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_messenger_bottom_bar"
        android:title="@string/employer.app.bottombar.messenger.title" />
    ...
    ...
</menu>
```

[image]

Comment: Add more context, maybe the XML and/or any custom things in your design. That issue looks very odd from the small snippet you posted.

Comment: Oh sorry it's done.

Comment: And your ` style="@style/BottomNavigation"` (this is where the issue is, most likely). Also, you can set the width to `match_parent` since you don't want ever to not see it like that (I know you are using `match_constraint`) :)

Answer (score 5):

Appreciate that this question is already a bit old, and I can't say for sure whether this will help you. But as it hasn't been answered yet, I'll share what I found when I worked on the same problem today. As it turned out, it was some entirely unrelated code (or so it seemed) that caused the issue.

Like you describe, the ripple animation got stuck sometimes. In my case, it always got stuck when navigating to one particular fragment. When that fragment was opened, it ran some code which at some point posted a task to some view's handler (`View.getHandler()`). Before posting the task, the function was calling `Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` to clear out the queue. It (probably) did so because of the false assumption that the only tasks in the queue would be the ones posted by earlier invocations of that function (in which case it would have made sense, to avoid redundant work).

However, even though you retrieve the handler from a specific view, it is one handler that is shared by anything going on on the UI thread. Therefore, if you happen to call the clear-all method `removeCallbacksAndMessages` at the wrong time, the animation that fades out the ripple effect on the navigation bar is cancelled as well.

After removing the call to `removeCallbacksAndMessages`, the ripple animation always completes as expected.

You can use tokens when posting a task to a handler to avoid this problem in a more elegant way, as that in turn allows you to cancel only tasks with a certain token. Tokens are not available for all variants of `post` and not on all API versions, though.

Comment: Spent a couple of hours searching for this exact bug and can confirm, the code seemed completely unrelated but was using UI thread's handler for its `post`s. As for API requirements, there is a `HandlerCompat` class that lets you use tokens on API < 28